# Passing arguments in function dynamically in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, arguments, parameter-passing

Does python support dynamic argument passing when I **call a function**?

```
  import itertools.product
  l = [1,2,3,95,5]
  for i in range(5):
      for n in itertools.product(l,l):
         #calculations that
         #reduce set size
```

I want through the iterations of i the product to be:

> i=1: product(l,l)
>
> i=2: product(l,l,l)
>
> i=3: product(l,l,l,l)
>
> ...

If I can recall correctly the only language I know that supports that kind of functionality is PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) accepts an optional keyword argument `repeat`:

So, you can do:

```
for n in itertools.product(l, repeat=i+1):
    ...
```

---

Alternatively, to dynamically pass argument, you can use `*args` (See [Unpacking argument lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)):

```
for n in itertools.product(*([l] * (i+1))):
    ...
```